# How to list items 5 by 5 in HorizontalListView in android on scrolling?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

Well right now i am able to display all items in horizontallistview with scroll, right now i need to display items 5 by 5 on scrolling in view like [this one](https://github.com/Seitk/InfiniteScrollPicker). I tried to find any link or sample codes, still i can't find anything. Can you guys suggest any link or ideas for solving my problem. Thanks in advance

XML:

```
<com.meetme.android.horizontallistview.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/user_GRIDS"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach is the ViewPager ([Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)) on Android. You can customize them as you want. Infinity scrolling is with them only a custom implementation.

Comment: can you give me any link using pageviewer for this.

Comment: I use the viewpager in one of my project as slide galery https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter